# Composition of Associahedra Operad

Tags: category-theory, homotopy-theory, operads

Is there a nice reference which explains in detail how composition works for the $A_\infty$-operad (associahedra operad)? It would be neat to have a visualization for low dimensions of what's happening (to get some intuition). I would be both happy with a detailed answer or a suggestion of where to find the proper definition.